# Starter questions on microcontroller programming development tools

Tags: embedded, arm, microcontroller, cortex-m

I was recently assigned a micro-controller programming task. I will need to program on [MKL05Z32VFM4](http://www.futureelectronics.com/en/Technologies/Product.aspx?ProductID=MKL05Z32VFM4FREESCALESEMICONDUCTOR1025520) device.

I was reading some programming tutorials on Microchip Technology's MPLAB IDE X, because that seems to have the most information, but looks like that IDE is only for Microchip products.

What development tools should I choose for MKL05Z32VFM4? Are there a generic IDE and simulator environment? Are there some tutorials for me to start to look at?

I apologize for a basic question. I am a decent general software developer, but I am very new to this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(this post will be partly useless if you plan to use some commercial toolchain like Keil, IAR or sth like that)

For ARM Cortex devices you have quite a lot of options available (; If you're in a mood for a bit of automatic translation you could check my website - I wrote a tutorial about (open source) toolchain for ARM - http://www.freddiechopin.info/pl/artykuly/35-arm/59-arm-toolchain-tutorial - unfortunately it's not translated to English, so you'll have to use google translate. There are also some other resources that you might find useful, especially my template/example projects for such toolchain (in Download). If you ever used Eclipse, Makefile and GCC this whole subject should be easy for you. Most of example projects will be close to what you need, but you should probably check example for STM32 (any) - which is a Cortex-M3, and the example for LPC1114 - which is a Cortex-M0.

As for the simulator, I personally think they're not worth the trouble, recent GCC toolchains disable it anyway, as it's only instruction simulator, you won't be able to easily simulate peripherals. If you want to simulate instructions just write your code for PC as it will work the same way (; If you need to check something on the real hardware you can use GDB and JTAG. As long as it's not some extremely expensive proprietary design (you can - again - check my website for other options) the tools are almost free - OpenOCD (GDB Server) is open-source, and you can buy a FTx232 based JTAG (the most popular kind for OpenOCD) starting at ~30$.

Big commercial toolchains sometimes have simulators with peripherals simulation, but these cost a few thousand € / year (;

Google around for "ARM Cortex" with keywords like: toolchain, gcc, openocd, debugging, jtag etc. to find some articles - there's a lot of it in the network.

Your question is really general, so pretty hard to answer, as we don't know what tools are you going to use, are you planing to use some external libraries, what type of work are you going to do with these devices etc.

From my experience contact with embedded world is often a huge shock for developers of PC software. It mostly works the same, but because resources are constrained you really should do things differently. You don't have "+infinity" of RAM, you should usually try to fit a lot of things in ROM and so on. And of course there's only C and C++, but in C++ you shouldn't use some of it's features (exceptions, RTTI, iostreams, parts of STL, ...), dynamic allocation of memory is not a good idea generally (with the chip you mentioned - 4kB of RAM - it's out of question in my opinion).

The chip you mentioned is really tiny, so it will probably be a bigger shock (;

Try to ask some specific question and give some more details about your project so we could give more detailed answers (;

Comment: Hi Freddie, a bit of googling leads me to http://www.coocox.org/CooCox_Builder.htm . What do you think of that IDE?

Comment: Hi Freddie, thanks again for your reply. Can you look at my new question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928198/microcontroller-programming-development-and-simulation It is much more specific than this post. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a Cortex-M0 device.  You can find *lots* of information online.  You can start at [arm.com](http://arm.com).  As far as toolchains go, gcc and clang are both free and support ARM and will work fine.  You can get ARM's tools too, if that's what you're into.  JTAG for debugging is going to cost you - most people use ARM's in-house RealView debugger or Trace32 from Lauterbach.  I've also used the BDI3000 from Abatron.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to say that "most people use RealView", which is too expensive for "most people"...

Comment: Sorry, I meant "realview or trace32".  That's just my experience, though.  Do you know some (good) cheaper alternatives?

Comment: I've mentioned a free/cheap solution in my answer - GDB, OpenOCD and a FTx232 based JTAG.

Comment: I also disagree that realview and trace32 are used by "most people".  I would say most people use openocd and an inexpensive ftdi based jtag device which is often found on eval boards in this class of hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Freescale MCU. Freescale's IDE of choice is CodeWarrior.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is the part manufacturer's site, generally they will have tools or links to recommended third parties as well as application notes and libraries.  Start at the [Freescale Kinetis KL0 series "Software & Tools"](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=KL0&nodeId=01624698C9E3EC&fpsp=1&tab=Design_Tools_Tab) page.

Freescale's own CodeWarrior tool is Eclipse based.

Comment: Looks like CodeWarrior is not free (actually quite expensive). Is there other alternative?

Comment: @CodeNoob:  You specifically didn't ask for free! The link I posted includes links to at least two alternatives.  The free/evaluation versions of both Keil MDK-ARM and IAR's EWBARM tools are good for 32K of code, so will suit your part, but not for commercial development, but since you want it free perhaps this is not for commercial use?  You could always of course use GCC, [Mentor Graphics](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/codesourcery) for example provide commercial, evaluation and free "lite" toolchains.

Comment: have you heard of CoIDE (http://www.coocox.org/CooCox_CoIDE.htm), and what do you think of it?

Comment: I have heard of it, but after the "discussion" between myself and its apparent author [here](http://embdev.net/topic/129986) (from about the 11th post down) some time ago, I have never been moved to investigate it.  In the end other than IAR and ARM (which owns Keil, so Keil too), and Green Hills, most development tools including CooCox use the GCC toolchain under the hood.  The value added by any particular IDE is variable.  Rowley Associates are another vendor you might look at; that differs in that while it uses GCC, they have their own debugger and C/C++ libraries.